# LUKS on top of BTRFS raid array

Tags: linux, raid, raid-1, btrfs, luks

How can I encrypt a partition that's `btrfs` RAIDed?

Running encryption on top of RAID is the best practice among a lot of sources even recommended by `cryptsetup` FAQ ([see 2.2](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#2-setup)). The reason I want this to be able to skip encryption/unlocking twice, replicate the configuration, removing key management overhead and to keep it simple and stupid.

Even though we have this best practice, almost all guides I find online using `btrfs` first encrypts the disks/partitions and then creates `btrfs` array on those disks. I do not wish that due to reasons above.

When running `luksFormat` interactively on RAIDed btrfs partitions I get:

```sh
WARNING: Device /dev/sdc1 already contains a 'btrfs' superblock signature.

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sdc1 irrevocably.
```

So I guess that this is the reason the RAID is being broken. Is there any way to get this topology (encrypting after creating `btrfs` RAIDed partitions) working without breaking the RAID?

### What I did

1. Create two partitions from two HDDs by running something like on each:

```sh
sudo parted --script <disk-name> \
    mklabel gpt \
    mkpart 'btrfs-raid1-partition' 1MiB 100%
```

2. Create BTRFS RAID 1 array between those partitions, such as:

```sh
sudo mkfs.btrfs \
  -L 'btrfs-raid1-array' \
  -d raid1 \
  -m raid1 \
  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 # Two partitions from two different disks
```

3. Install LUKS on one of the RAIDed partitions:

```sh
echo -n 'mysecret' | \
  sudo cryptsetup luksFormat \
  --batch-mode \
  --type luks2 \
  '/dev/sdc1/
```

### What I expect

I expect other device to be encrypted as well due to mirrored RAID 1 configuration however the other disk does not get the same configuration. I also I see that the other partition gets removed from the RAID array when I run `sudo btrfs fi show` or `sudo blkid --match-token TYPE=btrfs`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't do that, because Btrfs isn't a block-device RAID array, it is a *file system* that happens to include data mirroring.

---

First of all though, by doing what you did (i.e. trying to luksFormat the `sdc1` device), you'd get the same failure with any RAID system that Linux includes – even mdraid or dm-raid. They do not actually change how the underlying devices work – they work by giving you a *new* virtual device that implements the mirroring.

For example, setting up RAID1 via mdadm would create a virtual `/dev/md0` block device that you can mkfs or initialize for LUKS. However, even while the RAID array is "online", the original names like `/dev/sdc1` continue to represent the individual devices; directly writing to one of them would just go to that single disk and damage the array. The correct way to initialize LUKS over mdadm would be `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/md0`, for example.

(Even hardware RAID arrays work the same way; if you had an HP SmartArray card, for example, the OS would only see a virtual RAID disk and none of the individual physical disks.)

So where's the virtual device that Btrfs creates? There is none, because it *is not* a block-level RAID system; it is a file system on its own, which only happens to support multiple backing devices for data mirroring. (To get encryption with Btrfs you'd need to cut it apart and insert LUKS "in the middle", figuratively speaking.)

*(Well, you could use `losetup` to create a large image file in the Btrfs filesystem and initialize it with LUKS, but then you'd need to put *another* filesystem inside that LUKS volume, and running Btrfs on top of another Btrfs would be a bit silly.)*

This means you can't use LUKS "on top of" Btrfs. If you need data encryption, the other options are:

- Set up an ZFS array, as ZFS now has data encryption integrated without needing LUKS.
- Use regular mdadm (or dm-raid, or LVM) to create the RAID array, put LUKS on top of that, then use Ext4 or XFS in that LUKS volume. (Possibly Btrfs but *not* using Btrfs-level data mirroring, only mdadm. I think that's what Synology does...)
- Wait a few more years for Btrfs to finally gain file-level encryption, like ZFS or the common 'fscrypt' feature in Ext4 and XFS.

Comment: This is a great answer. What I was looking for from the first sentence and the rest clarified everything. Great example too and suggestions provided going forward. I was not expecting such as good answer, thank you. P.S: `sdc1` was just a test I was running and wouldn't be my real life usage, I updated question to remove confusion there.

Comment: That was not the point really – it would still have been the same if you had `sdc1` `sdd1`, or even bare `sdc` `sdd`.

Comment: Btrfs using the "single" or "dup" data profile on top of LUKS works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You said « almost all guides I find online using btrfs first encrypts the disks/partitions and then creates btrfs array on those disks. »… it would be interesting to know which guide you are talking about and follow.

I don’t follow you, you said you are going to use LUKS on a array disk and finally use it on a single disk (`/dev/sdc1`)

If you want to crypt a RAID array, assemble the array (with `md` for example), then crypt the array (with `cryptsetup` on `/dev/md0` or something like this). You can also crypt `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdc2` separately and build a btrFS on it (but it will double the encryption computations).

Note, before using a LUKS crypted disk, you need to use `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/_your_device_  _a_nick_name_` then use `/dev/mapper/_a_nick_name_`.

Note : a RAID1 array is made to avoid data loss when a disk is out of order… on top of `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdc2`, 2 partitions of the same disk, it won’t be useful.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear in the commands. I run the latest command on both partitions.

Guides I reviewed include among other similar:
https://mutschler.eu/linux/install-guides/ubuntu-btrfs-raid1-20-04/
https://balaskas.gr/btrfs/raid1.html#btrfs-and-raid1-over-luks

Thanks for the suggestion. I guess `md` or `ZFS` is the way to go for me as `btrfs` cannot seem to achieve this.

Regarding `sdc1`, `sdc2` I was just testing. In real usage I will use two different HDDs.

P.S: Updated answer to reduce some confusions caused.

Comment: Both guides propose you to crypt both partitions, then open them with `crypt_setup luksOpen` and use an other device (which is uncrypted) to initialize or mount the file system. Note that you have to deal with the device name (which contains crypted data), and a virtual device (which contains uncrypted data).